# 403 Forbidden for SharePoint version APIs BUT they work at design time AND all other REST calls work

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, outsystems

I have a strange problem whereby any REST APIs relating to SharePoint versions work when testing at design time but generate a 403 Forbidden error at runtime.  What is also odd is that all other REST API calls work fine at both design time and runtime and all the parameters are identical to the ones that don't work (headers etc.) and I've done a cut and paste on everything, but still anything relating to versions isn't working, although that might just be a red herring?

The app can successfully delete files and overwrite them, check in and out, etc. so seemingly there are no permission issues.  I have also tried checking a file out before reading the version information just in case (as check out is forced before any actions can be carried out on this site) but that didn't work either.

This is an example of one of the calls that is causing the error:

https://mycompany.SharePoint.com/sites/{SiteName}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/{SiteName}/Shared%20Documents/{FilenameAndPath}')/version

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-the-document-based-on-version-number-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api):

```
https://sharepoint/_api/web/folders/getbyurl('Documents')/files/getbyurl('myfile.docx')/versions?$filter=VersionLabel eq '2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, however I get the exact same problem using that method also.  It works when testing it at design time but when I run it I get a 403 Forbidden error.  It is anything to do with versions that causes the problems and everything else works fine - very confusing!!

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem, using 'insomnia' works like a charm. But can't make it work in python or using curl.   Digest and permission doesn't seem to be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Accept** and **Content-Type** headers in the ***OnBeforeRequest*** REST API callback.

I have found that when testing the IDE will send for instance `"application/json"` for both, but at runtime, the platform adds `";utf-8"` to the values of these headers. The requests are then often rejected without a proper error specification/declaration.